# Why do we need to construct a dataset reference in bigquery?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am learning bigquery with python notebook, and I found out the very first lines of code as follows:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
hn_dataset_ref = client.dataset('hacker_news', project='bigquery-public-data')
hn_dset = client.get_dataset(hn_dataset_ref)
```

My question is why do we need to construct a dataset reference?

Can we do in a shorter way like below?

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
hn_dset = client.get_dataset('bigquery-public-data.hacker_news')`
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it in the shorter way. When you use a string, the method will actually create a [DatasetReference](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/0d2a88d8072154cfc9152afd6d26a60ddcdfbc73/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py#L586).

The long method was the old way to do it, and it is actually [deprecated](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/blob/0d2a88d8072154cfc9152afd6d26a60ddcdfbc73/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py#L355), so it is no longer recommended its use.